# .NET tutorial cant understand purpose of certain fields in .cs Model files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-deployment

I have been following the a tutorial on ASP.NET - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer

They start with building the data layer (the application is a shopping website for toys where each item belongs to one of four categories). So, they start with building out the "products" and "categories" tables. The products table has the following code -

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int ProductID { get; set; }

[Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Name")]
public string ProductName { get; set; }

[Required, StringLength(10000), Display(Name = "Product Description"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Description { get; set; }

public string ImagePath { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Price")]
public double? UnitPrice { get; set; }

public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

In the code above, I don't understand what the purpose of the last field,

```
 public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

is.

And then similarly the categories .cs file has the following code -

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int CategoryID { get; set; }

[Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Name")]
public string CategoryName { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Product Description")]
public string Description { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Again, what is the purpose of

```
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

And then finally, there is a context class with the following code -

```
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
  public class ProductContext : DbContext
  {
    public ProductContext() : base("WingtipToys")
  {
}
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
  }
}
```

This one has a field called Products but so did the second .cs file. So, what is this one for and won't it conflict with the other "Products" object which was also global?

Comment: Do you have any idea about Entity Framework ?

Comment: probably not. that's why he is following a tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read a little about relationships in Entity Framework, this are called Navigation Properties, as you can see a product have a Category, so Instead of just having the the ID you have a full object.

```
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

As a Category have many products, the navigation property its a collection.

```
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

The context class its related to your database, You are letting EF know that you want this entities in your database, and this DbSet is how you access this tables that you are creating for your database. The base"WingtipToys" is name of the connection string, if you are using code first if the database does not exist it will create the connection string and the database.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
  public class ProductContext : DbContext
  {
    public ProductContext() : base("WingtipToys")
  {
}
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Those are what are called navigation properties. They enable you to access the entities that are linked via foreign key relationships.

Here is how you can use them.

```
var product = dbContext.Products.First();
var theCategoryOfTheProduct = product.Category;


var category = dbContext.Categories.First();
var allProductsInTheCategory = category.Products.ToList();
```

So, in Products model, you'll find    `public virtual Category Category { get; set; }` which tells you the `Product` can have only one `Category`. But on the Category model you'll find public `virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }` -- a collection -- because there could be multiple `Products` in the `Categories`

Comment: Thanks.. got it. Ill look into these. But the public variable Products in the code segments above ends up defined two times in two different files. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: Never mind. I think they are fields of different classes, so there is no ambiguity.